# using of Swingworker giving incorrect results

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

My project follows the following flow:
[image]

I want to use swingworker.Here is the way i am using it but the results are not coming correct

In my GUI code, my code is this for executing the principal class

I have written the following lines of code in buttons code

```
     Main f2 = new Main();

    f2.execute();
```

In my Principal class ,i have done this

```
      class Principalclass extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
          {
            @Override
            public Void doInBackground() throws IOException 
             {
               //while loop
              }
           @Override
            public void done() {
              System.out.println("I am DONE");
              GUI b = new GUI();   
              b.ShowFrame();   //calls the function of the GUI to display frame
             }
```

Now this code without printing "I am DONe" displays the GUI frame.I am confused if i have to do some changes in classes 2,3 and 4 bcz i am using swingworker or if i have to do further changes only in Principalclass.Secondly,the application which should take 15 mins to complete its task,it just takes 2 secs :(.May be i am doing something seriously wrong because i am using swing worker for the first time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your swing worker and do it from EDT. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for more info.